# MS-Access VBA DoCmd.RunSQL issue

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to run some SQL from a button however I keep getting runtime error 2342 "A runSQL action requires an argument consisting of a SQL statement." I know the statement works when I run it direct.
As far as I can see I have set it up exactly as per the example in the dev centre documents but it's still failing - code details below, any advice on what I am doing stoopid gratefully received! Thanks

Example in document:

```
Public Sub DoSQL() 
     Dim SQL As String 

    SQL = "UPDATE Employees" & _ 
          "SET Employees.Title = 'Regional Sales Manager'" & _ 
          "WHERE Employees.Title = 'Sales Manager'" 

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL 

End Sub
```

My code:

```
Private Sub btnTestNextSeqNum_Click()
    Dim GetSeqNum As String

    GetSeqNum = "SELECT dt1.MaxAccSeqNum FROM (SELECT Item.AccessionYear AS AccYear, Max(Item.AccessionSequenceNumber) AS MaxAccSeqNum FROM Item GROUP BY Item.AccessionYear) AS DT1 WHERE dt1.AccYear = 2020;"  

    msgbox GetSeqNum   *this shows that the variable does contain the full SQL statement

    DoCmd.RunSQL GetSeqNum 

End Sub
```

Comment: `DoCmd.RunSQL` is designed for action queries, i.e. those that update data, delete data, or update table structures, It is **not** designed to perform data selection.

Comment: The above SQL returns records (SELECT query). What do you plan to do with it? Need to loop over the records? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you Applecore - I'd missed that specific point

Comment: I am trying to find a maximum sequence number by year (business key) so I can add one when inserting new record

Comment: Have a look at the `DMax()` function here https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dmax.php and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.dmax

Comment: Thank you both, that helps me :-) (I knew I was doing something dumb!!) :-D

Comment: Or instead of using DMax, you could open a recordset using the SQL statement.

Comment: The UPDATE SQL has errors and would fail. Need space in front of SET and WHERE so string doesn't 'run together' when compiled.

Comment: Looks like I can't vote or accept answer yet - not been here long enough! (unless of course I'm missing it again) Thanks though guys, I have solved my problem